# No repeated contact from content://sms/inbox

Tags: android, group-by, message, distinct, android-contentprovider

I'm a newbie in Android development.
I'm doing a simple application to read the text messages of the phone.
I know how many problems there are around the content provider content://sms but... It's too difficult for me to write a custom one, so I'll use it, for the moment.

The problem: when I query content://sms/inbox I get all the messages so when I try to list them in a ListActivity I have the same contact repeated for each message he/she has. Basically this is correct, I understand it but I need something else, something "more professional".
First of all because:
1- a query so big takes long time on phones
2- obviously it doesn't make any senses have all the messages listed in this way.

The simplest thing would be using DISTINCT or... if not, but very bad because it queries again all the messages, a GROUP BY. The problem is: GROUP BY is not recognize because, correctly, what is behind a content provider there can be something different from a DB. Apparently DISTINCT is accepted but it doesn't do any differences if it is used.
I have been freaking out for 3 days to find a solution without filtering messages by myself after getting the query of them.

This is my little and simple piece of code where I try to do the query:
    List smsList = new ArrayList();

```
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
       String order = new String("date DESC");
       String[] projection = new String[]{"DISTINCT thread_id, address, body, _id"};
       String selection = new String("GROUP BY address"); //this doesn't work
       Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, order);

       // Read the sms data and store it in the list
       if(c.moveToFirst()) {
           for( i=0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
               SMSData sms = new SMSData();
               sms.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
               sms.setNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
               sms.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")).toString());
               sms.setPersonName(getContactNameFromNumber(sms.getNumber()));
               smsList.add(sms);
               //Log.v(TAG,"il nome è: "+smsList.get(i).getPersonName()+" e il numero è: "+smsList.get(i).getNumber());
               c.moveToNext();
           }
       }

       c.close();
```

I hope someone can help me!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `GROUP BY thread_id` , see more details in my github repository [SmsMessenger](https://github.com/alishari/SmsMessenger), you can get it by following query:

```
    cursor = MyApplication.getContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms")
            , null
            , "address IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (thread_id"
            , null
            , null);
```